# Добавить индексацию элементов списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

как в join передать id элемента в списке?
в списке `имя_списка ['a123','b322','c228']`

`some text id1 = {{  имя_списка | join(', id = ') }}`

выводит
`some text id1 = a123, id = b322, id = c228`

необходимо чтоб после id был номер элемента
`some text id1 = a123, id2 = b322, id3 = c228`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `enumerate` и `f-строки`:

```py
lst = ['a123','b322','c228']
print(', '.join(f'id{i} = {x}' for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1)))
```

Вывод:

```
id1 = a123, id2 = b322, id3 = c228
```